# Puzzling wildcard problem in IIS7 & Module

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We have an ASP.NET 3.5 app running in IIS6 we're migrating to IIS7 & the integrated pipeline. Our app does some very simple URL rewriting to examine a URL like this:

```
website.com/dealer/page.aspx
```

stripping 'dealer' out, looking it up in the DB for context and going to page.aspx.

In IIS6 this was a wildcard map. I moved the module to the right place in web.config for IIS7:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="ModuleRewriter" 
         type="Insignia.Catalog2.ModuleRewriter, Insignia.Catalog2"
         preCondition="" />
```

And it works - almost. Paths like these work:

```
website.com/dealer/page.aspx
website.com/dealer/
```

The latter defaults to the index.aspx page. My problem is, this one doesn't:

```
website.com/dealer
```

note the missing slash at the end. I get a 404. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

It has something to do with the Static file handler - if I disable that, the URL maps correctly, but then static stuff doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it to work by modifying the modules tag:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="True">
```

but this is definately cargo-cult-ish because i don't know what it's doing yet.